# Update Panel in a UserControl Register Client Side Script

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a couple of update panels inside a user control. One of the update panels is wrapped by a div that opens in a jQuery UI dialog.

On post back I want to close the dialog by registering a client side script bu the following code doesn't seem to output to the screen.

```
    void EventEditControl_EventUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindGrid();
        CloseDialog("dialog-form");
        upGrid.Update();
    }

    private void CloseDialog(string dialogId)
    {
        string script = string.Format(@"closeDialog('{0}')", dialogId);
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), UniqueID, script, true);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that `this` is a user control which contains a div and the div contains the update panel.  If so then that is the issue.  Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb350750.aspx):

> Client script blocks that are
>   registered by using this method are
>   sent to the page only when control
>   represents **a control that is inside an
>   UpdatePanel** control that is being
>   updated.

If my previous assumption is correct then `this` is not inside an update panel, it contains an update panel.  Instead replace `this` with a reference to a control inside your update panel, if need be add a hidden field or literal to do the job.